# How to send a query parameter with Mac Safari HLS calls?

Tags: safari, video.js, http-live-streaming

Actually we have deployed our HLS segments and index files on akamai cdn, access of which requires a query parameter or a cookie. Because of the policies of safari, you can't set a other domain(akamai) cookie so sending cookie with network calls is not possible. Now as Safari natively supports HLS, appending query parameters with .ts or .m3u8 calls are not looking possible too. What should i do to run HLS on safari?

(Also library videojs-contrib-hls is not working with Safari, i have tried it with every possible hack.It is giving errors time to time.)

Comment: Ask for cookieless auth using paths

Answer (score -1):

You can use a on-the-fly packager / manifest generator, like [Unified Streaming](http://www.unified-streaming.com/) to append user session specific query parameters.

The [Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/) is able to attach query parameters to VOD HLS streams in Safari if the [`native_hls_parsing`](https://developer.bitmovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001561533-Bitmovin-Player-API-Documentation-v7#interfaces/playerconfigapi.tweaksconfig.html#native_hls_parsing) flag is set to `true` in the configuration.